# I want to use image upload box with hiding input field . when i hide the input field it can't work properly .. any suggesition?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am less experienced plz help me out to resolve this problem . i want just image upload box by clicking on it input field work. thanks in advance

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#picker')
        .attr('src', e.target.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 180px;
}

input[type=file] {
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  display: ;
  background: ;
}

.card-1 {
  width: 180px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
}

.card-1:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card card-1">
  <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
  <img id="picker" src="http://placehold.it/180" alt="your image" />
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.. Could you please explain step by step what's the issue?

Comment: thanks for your quick response . i want to hide input field with out lost its functionality on my form when i hide this my input field attribute can't works .

Comment: So once the file is selected, you want to hide `input type=file` element?

Comment: thank you so much sir for your help .

Answer (score 0):

You can call `.click()` on `this.previousElementSibling.click()` at `onclick` at `<img>` element that is next element sibling of `<input type="file">` element.

Note `file` at `input[type=file]` should be surrounded by quotes at `css` `input[type="file"]`.  Set `display` set to `none` at `input[type="file"]` element if element should not be displayed.

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#picker')
        .attr('src', e.target.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 180px;
}

input[type="file"] {
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.card-1 {
  width: 180px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
}

.card-1:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card card-1">
  <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
  <img onclick="this.previousElementSibling.click()" id="picker" src="http://placehold.it/180" alt="your image" />
</div>
```